# is influxdb backward compatible with graphite/carbon api?

Tags: graphite, influxdb

We are evaluating replacing graphite as our monitoring system with an InfluxDB based stack and wondering if InfluxDB supports for Graphite line protocol is fully backward compatible with Graphite/Carbon api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write Graphite format data to InfluxDB in two ways.

### Using Telegraf

Using the `socket_listener` in Telegraf you can accept [Graphite Format](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/DATA_FORMATS_INPUT.md#graphite) data. This data can then be forwarded on to InfluxDB.

### Using InfluxDB

InfluxDB can process Graphite format data via the [Graphite Service](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/master/services/graphite/README.md) that can be configured in the `[[graphite]]` section of the InfluxDB configuration file.

Comment: Small correction about Telegraf. 1) tcp and udp listeners are deprecated in favor of socket_listener, and 2) http_listener support only InfluxDB input and not graphite (see https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/http_listener)

Comment: some assistance with the second implementation - I configured my instance of graphios to point to influxDB's graphite service, but no data is being populated, even though spool is being processed. Is this not the preferred way?

Answer (score 1):

Writing data in graphite line protocol is possible, reading data stored in influx via Graphite API is not (natively).

[InfluxGraph](https://github.com/InfluxGraph/influxgraph) is a third party storage finder for Graphite API that can handle that.